# Import activity cannot retrieve data from Salesforce Report into Salesforce Data Extension

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketing-cloud-connect

We have integrated my marketing cloud user and sales cloud snadbox user, the Salesforce import activity in email studio can also be created successfully. However, everytime i run the import activity, target data extension of this import activity canbe created, but the salesforce data extension cannot get the data from the related salesforce reports. The alert goes as " "Warning: Import aborted while processing Batch 1 in SalesForceSourceReader. One or more errors indicating why the import was aborted may be logged to the dbo.ImportError table. But when we use admin users with sales cloud admin user mapping to run this import activity, there is no error then. if we use the "Standard User" profile in Sales Cloud, the error comes out again. not sure if there is a permission needs to be enabled for Sales Cloud user to get the Salesforce Report Data. Thank you!

Comment: Can you take a screen shot of your import activity settings?

Comment: Thank you! we have found the reason behind it, it's becuase some fields within the import activities are not accessible by the related Sales Cloud users.